# How to convert a vector of int to vector of const char*

Tags: c++, string, vector, char, constants

I know how to convert from vector of int to vector of string

But is it even possible to convert from vector of int to vector of const char*?
Seems almost impossible...

For example, the following code will be wrong:

```
int n=3;
vector<int> vec;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){vec.push_back(i);}

vector<const char*> charArray;
for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
{
    std::string s = std::to_string(vec[i]);
    charArray.push_back( s.c_str() );
}
for( int i=0;i<charArray.size();i++)
{
    cout<<charArray[i]<<endl;
}
```

It will print the following on the screen:
3
3
3

Comment: Please tag your question with the corresponding programming language

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you have to explain what relationship you want the result to have to the original.

Comment: Just stick to std::string in the vector, and convert to char only when you need the char sequence.

Comment: I wish I could. It was required to utilize a function from an internal library which requires an input as a vector<const char*>.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an `std::vector` of `const char*` as input to a library function, you can do it like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

void LibraryFunction(std::vector<const char*>& charVec)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < charVec.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << charVec[i] << " ";
    }
}

std::string to_string(int i)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> vec(arr, arr + 3); // your vector from before
    std::vector<std::string> strVec;
    strVec.reserve(vec.size());
    std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(strVec), to_string);
    { // use block to make sure charVec is removed before strVec.
        std::vector<const char*> charVec;
        charVec.reserve(strVec.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < strVec.size(); ++i)
        {
             charVec.push_back(strVec[i].c_str());
        }
        LibraryFunction(charVec); // call your lib function here
    } // now strVec can be safely removed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is to use a local string vector to safeguard the space those charVec points to.

Comment: @user3404592 Exactly. The overhead is small and the automatic memory management is a huge benefit. Please accept (and maybe upvote) this answer if it solves your task! Thanks :)